# Pandas: cant strip '-' from number in CSV

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following problem, I have two separate python scripts. 
The first converts a CSV file to a new format (dropping certain columns and removing dollar signs)

A separate scripts reads all of the converted CSV files and create a single large script from those, grouping the data by certain keys.

All of this works well enough, except for the fact that I keep running into the following problem.

One of the columns in both files *Money Out* sometimes contains values starting with a '-'  (-235.93). I want to remove this symbol from the file.

I've put the following code in both scripts, yet I am unable to remove the symbol. 
The data is sometimes numeric and sometimes a string. I thought that unifying it to string and using the 'replace' method would solve the problem, yet it didnt. I also used the build in pandas method, yet to no avail.

```
df['Money Out'] = df['Money Out'].astype(str)
df['Money Out'] = df['Money Out'].replace('-', '')
df['Money Out'].replace('-', '', inplace=True)
```

Does anyone have an idea of what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: You want `.str.replace('-', '')` - `Series.replace` is something different...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code:

```
df['Money Out'].replace('-', '', inplace=True)
```

is using [`Series.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.replace.html) which is a different thing (replaces an *exact match* of the column or a regex with a value) than the [`Series.str.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) function (more traditional replace a substring present anywhere with another), you can use:

```
df['Money Out'] = df['Money Out'].str.replace('-', '')
```

to remove any hyphens from your text.

Answer (score 1):

Try to do this

```
df['Money Out'] = df.apply(lambda r: ("%s"%(r['Money Out'] or "0.0")).replace("-",""), axis=1)
```